# Extract the minimum positive value of each row in a matrix?

Tags: octave

I have a matrix like this 
A =

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 7, NA;
 0, 0, 3, 5, 7, NA, NA;
 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NA;
 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, NA;]
```

I want to extract the minimum values in each row  of the matrix A that is greater than 0 into a vector B:

```
B = [1;3;2;4]
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A(A<=0)=NA;
B=min(A, [], 2)
```

As suggested by Matt I'll explain this a little bit. Because you don't want results <=0 I set them to NA. You already have some in your data and the "min" operation will ignore them.

In the second step we search the minimum in the rows (2. dimension).

Comment: @Matt: thank you for the hint. It's possible or usual to get downvotes if the answer is correct but not explained in detail?

Comment: @Andy: It all depends on the person voting. Personally; I don't *downvote* a short answer, but I certainly won't upvote it either. Now you've expanded your answer, I'm more than happy to give you a +1, however.

Comment: @Le Quang Nam: I'm new to stackoverflow and not familiar with user habits. Why don't you give a upvote if the answer is "excellent"?

Comment: @ Andy: I am not enough reputation, so I can't give you an upvote.

Comment: @ Andy: Now I have enough reputation, so I just give you an upvote. Thanks!